# Priority of threads on timeline

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

Let's say I have some code like:

```
let offlineRequest = OfflineRequest(params: ["id": summaryId], apiAction: ApiAction.deleteSummary)
let offlineRequestsStore = ApplicationManager.instance().offlineRequestsStore
offlineRequestsStore.storeRequest(offlineRequest: offlineRequest) // a call with adding one more request but which call other async function to decrease RequestStore.pendingRequestInQueue() count when the call to the server is executed.

let offlineRequests = RequestStore.pendingRequestInQueue() // Does this code make any senese? Could this line be called simultaneouslywith with the line above assuming it has async call in it? 
if offlineRequests {
self.presenter?.updateHistoryDataSource()
} else {
self.getHistoryWorkouts()
}
```

I want to understand its timeline of executing operations (tasks)

If, for example, I have next lines of code

line 1. func call in main thread

line 2. func call in async

line 3. func call in main thread

Will **line 3** will be executed before **line 2**, assuming that line 2 is returning from an async thread when line 3 is called at the same time?

I mean does the main thread have some priority on a timeline, or can two tasks be executed at the same time and when line 3 on the main thread will check the result it could be changed?

Comment: The execution on the current thread will generally carry on more quickly than the execution of the `async` block, but you have zero assurances to that affect. One should simply avoid race conditions, regardless of how benign they may appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will line 3 will be executed before line 2

No. This is not promised.

> does the main thread have some priority on a timeline

Sometimes, but this is not promised, and is not always true.

> can two tasks be executed at the same time

Yes, if you have multiple cores. And also yes, for a weaker version of "at the same time," even if you have one.

Comment: fantastic Rob! thanks for the provided answer and detailed explanation!